# How does Inserting a New Node into a Linked List Exactly Work in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

So take the `push` function below (Insert at beginning of list). I know that it first allocates memory for a node named `new_node` and then you give it it's values like `x = 5`, and then set the `head` to point to `new_node`.

```c
void push(int x, struct Node** head_ref) {
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = x; //New data
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); //Connects the new_node to what beginning of the node
    (*head_ref) = new_node; //The head now points to the new node
}
```

What I can't wrap my head around is what is really happening with `new_node`? When I run the function for `n` amount of times after the functions have run, I'm able to traverse through the list with no problems along with being able to print the values of the new nodes, but wouldn't there be a problem since we're using the same variable name `new_node` every time we run the function? Does it have something to do with how the computer is working with the allocated memory or could it be something else? I haven't been able to find much info on my topic to answer my question.

Comment: Paper, a pencil, boxes, and arrows. Sounds trivial, but you'd be amazed how clearly they help in deciphering dynamic data structures like linked lists.

Comment: It's an ephemeral, local variable. It's like a piece of paper that you write a value on, in this case that value is the unique address of a piece of allocated memory to hold the new node. Later when you want the head of the list to point to that memory, you retrieve the address from the piece of paper and you store its value (via `(*head_ref) = new_node`) in the place where the head of the list can be retrieved from. And then you discard the piece of paper. Next time around, you have a new piece of paper to write on.

Comment: `new_node` is (just) a pointer, not the node itself.  You need to understand the difference between a pointer and what it points at.

Comment: @jarmod So tell me if I'm right. So once I run my function it's given my new node a place in memory then gives it whatever value you pass into it and then makes `head` point to that place in memory and make `new_node` point to the next node and since it was allocated it won't disappear from memory and then the next time I run the function, it'll make a new memory address and so on. Right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It allocates memory for a new node, fills in its data value, and then hooks it into the existing linked list (by first making its `next` pointer point to the node that's currently at the head of the list, and then pointing head at it, the new node). Like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU0KxLgNM9E

Answer (score 0):

> but wouldn't there be a problem since we're using the same variable name new_node every time we run the function?

No; the variable is declared and defined on the function scope. In other words, it's a new variable every time you run the function. If you do the following simple function:

```c
int aNumber() {
    int x = 4;
    return ++x;
}
```

then that function will return 5 every time, because `x` is declared and defined inside the function, and so only exists while the function is being run.